# Trouble using unicode characters with WhatsApp's send API

Tags: javascript, api, unicode, whatsapp, emoji

I am trying to allow users of my web-based javascript game to share their progress with friends via social media. I would like to include some emojis in these messages, similar to below functionality from another web-based game at https://wordlewebsite.com/wordle-unlimited

[image]

Above message is generated via WhatsApp API's `send` endpoint, the request to this API looks like this in my browser.

[image]

Note how the emojis are actually rendered in the URL bar, but not on the page itself, where they are rendered as �. In the end, however, the emojis render correctly in the message, which is what counts.

Now, when I construct a similar message with the escaped unicode strings for the three-colored blocks (: \u{1F7E8} : \u{1F7E9} ⬛: \u{2B1B}) in JavaScript, I get messages like below.
[image]

What's more, in my implementation, the API request looks different in the browser as well (shown below).

[image]

This time, the url bar is showing � as well.

Here is the relevant code that I use to construct the string that is sent to the API.

```
function getEmojiGrid()
{
    let colorEmojiGrid = ``
    for (let i = 0; i < allColorCodes.length; ++i)
    {
        let row = allColorCodes[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < row.length; ++j)
        {
            let color = row[j];
            if (color=="b")
            {
                colorEmojiGrid += '\u{2B1B}' //unicode works for twitter but not for whatsapp
            }
            else if (color == "y")
            {
                colorEmojiGrid += '\u{1F7E8}'
            }
            else if (color == "g")
            {
                colorEmojiGrid += '\u{1F7E9}'
            }
            
        }
        colorEmojiGrid += "\n"
    }
    
    return colorEmojiGrid;
}
```

I then dynamically inject this string into html like so.

```
let emojiBoard = getEmojiGrid();
shareBody = `<div class='shareon'><a class='facebook' data-url='${shareURL}'>Facebook</a><a class='reddit' data-url='${shareURL}' data-title="I guessed this word in ${currentRow}/6 tries. Can you beat my score?">Reddit</a></div><div class='shareon'><a class='whatsapp' data-title="I guessed this word in ${currentRow}/6 tries. \n\n${emojiBoard}\n\nCan you guess the word?\n\n" data-url='${shareURL}'>WhatsApp</a><a class='twitter' data-title="I guessed this word in ${currentRow}/6 tries. \n\n${emojiBoard}\n\nCan you guess the word?\n\n" data-url='${shareURL}'>Twitter</a></div>`
```

From here, a third-party library (Shareon: https://github.com/kytta/shareon) grabs it and forms the final string that is sent to the WhatsApp API.

As is mentioned in one of the comments in my code, the emojis render perfectly when using, e.g., the twitter API, but something is different with the WhatsApp API, and I'd like to know how I can fix this.

**Edit**: I just tried accessing my game on mobile and sharing to WhatsApp, and in this scenario the emojis get rendered correctly. However, on desktop they still do not get rendered correctly at all.